# div height is not set properly after the contained image is rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-rotation

Im using bootstrap modal, and have the requirement to show pictures in the modal body. Image width and height is varying. I also have a requirement to be able to zoom in/out, and rotate the pics by 90° left/right. So the modal size is varying also, based on the current pic size and rotation.

*The image container itself has defined min and max width and height, to make sure the modal stays in screen. Overflow handling for the image container is mandatory, because the image dimensions can be bigger then the prev mentioned min/max modal width/height. And you must be able to see or at least scroll to any part of the image.*

Zoom is working fine, the problem comes in when the rotation happens.The image rotates as expected, but the image containers (`#imageModalBody`) height is still  the height before the rotation, despite the fact, that i set it to an exact px value in `setImageContainerDimensions` function. And this leaves a buch of empty space below the picture. *(Also this is true in reverse situations as well -> if the original image width > height then the empty space will be on the right side of the image after rotation)*

[functionally identical JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/58345/)

Original CSS:

```
#imageModalBody {
    overflow: auto;
    margin:auto;
    width: fit-content;
    max-height: 825px;
}

#imageModalBody, #imageModalBody .img-fluid{
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
#imageModalBody .img-fluid {
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
}
#imageModalBody.rotate90 .img-fluid {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#imageModalBody.rotate180 .img-fluid {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%, -100%);
}
#imageModalBody.rotate270 .img-fluid {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

Original JS:

```
gallery = {
    /* ... */
    zoom: function (context, step) {
        var modal = context.closest('.modal');
        var image = modal.find('.img-fluid');
        image.width(image.width() + step);
        gallery.setImageContainerDimensions(modal.find('#imageModalBody'));
    },
    rotate: function (context, step) {
        var container = context.closest('.modal').find('#imageModalBody');
        var rotation = parseInt(container.attr('data-rotation'));
        var newRotation = rotation + step;

        newRotation = newRotation < 0 ? (newRotation + 360) % 360 : newRotation % 360;
        container.removeClass('rotate' + rotation);
        container.addClass('rotate' + newRotation);
        container.attr('data-rotation', newRotation);
        gallery.setImageContainerDimensions(container, newRotation);
    },
    setImageContainerDimensions: function (container, rotation) {
        var image = container.find('.img-fluid');
        rotation = rotation || parseInt(container.attr('data-rotation'));
        if (rotation % 180 == 90) {
            container.width(image.height() + 17).height(image.width());
        }
        else {
            container.width(image.width() + 17).height(image.height());
        }
    },
    getModalElement: function (eventItem) {
        var modal = $(`<div class="modal fade" id="imageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="imageModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="imageModalTitle">${eventItem.title}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="imageModalBody" data-rotation="0" class="rotate0"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`);
        modal.prepend(gallery.getModalControlElement(eventItem.modalImg));
        modal.find('#imageModalBody').append(eventItem.modalImg);
        return modal;
    },
    getImageElement: function (item) {
        return $(`<img class="img-fluid" src="${item.imageData}" alt="${item.title}" title="${item.title}">`);
    },
    /* ... */
}
```

How can i get rid of the empty space below/next to the picture? If any more info needed, pls let me know.

Comment: Coud you give a working example? Rather than screenshots of html code. Thanks

Comment: Here it is, basicly doing the same thing: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/58345/

Comment: Why not use `canvas` for this kind of image transformations?

Comment: Yeah, thats the next step, seemd easier to do this with css transformation at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this css rule

```
#imageModalBody {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

See the result https://jsfiddle.net/xs57dy60/

Comment: yes, this solves the problem in some cases. But in the case, that the original pic is larger then the allowed `max-height` (825px - for the modal to stay in the screen), then the pic will extend under the screen and cant be viewn. - Sorry, my bad, i messed up that part of the description. I'll edit it in.

Comment: In that case you can easily add this rule dynamically within your javascript function.